# What should we do about cross-posting?

Tags: discussion

In two days, I've twice merged questions, because we've had two instances of cross postings (one involved three sites, and is still being dealt with). This has also happened before in many cases, many resulting in merges. The usual other sites involved are Mathematics and Physics.

The typical way that the moderators on HSM deal with this is to contact at least one moderator from the other site(s) in chat, and come to some kind of an agreement on the matter. We've been working off of the idea that cross-posting *exact duplicates* of questions on HSM and one or more other Stack Exchange sites is not a good thing, primarily because it spreads information out in different places that could fit together better in one.

It would be good to get the community's opinion on the matter, since this sort of official consultation hasn't actually happened. We've been assuming that this kind of thing - not allowing exact cross-site duplicates - is what the community wants. This might not be true, though.

What should be our strategies for dealing with cross-posting? Should we continue with our current plan, or should we do something different?

Answer (score 3):

One solution to cross-posting - though it may not even be possible depending on how exactly the various SE sites are implemented - would be to allow the multiple questions to be merged into a single one which is visible in all affected sites.

This could either be with the primary question being "hosted" in eg HSM and "aliased" in M and P; or else a symmetrical "replication" type solution - in either case the question and all answers and comments would be shared/visible in all affected sites.

Would this be remotely feasible?

I can certainly see that rep points would be an added complication :)

Comment: There is no way to do this at the moment, though various feature requests to this effect have been made on meta SE (e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199989). At the moment, the closest thing we can do is to migrate the cross-post from one site to the other, and then close it as a duplicate on the second site.